# Yodlee: getMFAResponseForSite is not returning the MFA (security QA) form

Tags: yodlee

I am working on adding MFA enabled utility accounts in yodlee through ASP.NET web services. 
After adding the site through "addSiteAccount1" API, the response returned as "REFRESH_TRIGGERED" with memsiteAccountId and then called upon API "getMFAResponseForSite". I have called this API in both my web service and in google chrome rest client app. In rest client app it returns MFA forms correctly, but in my web service it returns the following response,

```
{"Body":"{\"isMessageAvailable\":false,\"timeOutTime\":0,\"itemId\":0,\"memSiteAccId\":10215365,\"retry\":true}","isValid":true}
```

But, when i called on "getSiteRefreshInfo" API, in both cases it returns "REFRESH_TRIGGERED" only. There is no error in my get MFA response service. This is weird to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call this getMFAResponseForSite in loop of 2-4 second difference.  As sometimes getting the MFA question which bank website is asking takes time and in very first call of getMFAResponseForSite you will not receive the MFA Security Question.

Hope this helps.